# Temporarily Storing Decrypted Data in Memory

Tags: c++, linux, security, c++11, encryption

**Background**

I am working on a simple application in native C++11 which uses Microsoft's Cassablanca REST framework to communicate with various remote endpoints.  To do this, I have to cryptographically sign the various requests with some secret provided by whichever API is being targeted.  By linking Cassablanca I already have OpenSSL so the actual crypto is reasonably straight-forward.

Now, the tricky part is how to store the secrets themselves.  My plan is to AES encrypt a JSON file with all of the goodies using a symmetric key from the user's brain (read: password) so that it does not have to be stored on disk.

**The Question**

**What is a secure way to store the decrypted secrets in memory during the execution of the application?**  This is not another "how do I store secrets on disk so the user doesn't have to do anything" question.

My big concern is that someone will be able to examine my application's memory externally and find the appropriate regions containing the goodies.  I know Windows provides credstores and protected memory however I am on Linux and would prefer a platform-agnostic solution if possible.  There is also a significant chance that this will be deployed to a VM cluster so protected memory may only buy limited assurances (though, still better than nothing).

Finally, I know that *any* cryptographic system can be overcome with sufficiently large amount of money+time or a large enough rubber hose.  That being said, I would still like to be as secure as possible as an exercise in Good™ coding practice.

**My constraints are:**

- Must be able to access secrets for signing the various requests quickly.  Milliseconds count here but I am willing to accept a slowdown if security is truly improved.
- I would prefer a minimum of external libraries and to use native C++11 where possible.  I feel like this should be doable with what I already have (Cassablanca which requires OpenSSL, Boost, libcrypt).
- Finally, it should be able to accommodate a reasonably large number of secrets / requests.  My application domain is basically a giant parallelization problem and scalability is key.

**What I already know to do:**

- Never ever store sensitive material on disk unencrypted.  This includes usage of disk-backed containers and whatnot.
- An old but useful trick: attach a debugger instance to prevent remote debugging from external process.
- Build without debug symbols and strip final executable.
- Minimize in-application access to data to only the parts which truly need it.
- Destroy sensitive information as soon as it is no longer needed (Ex. NULL out user password as soon as decryption is finished, etc).
- Do not trust anybody to sanitize memory for me.  Manually overwrite areas with NULL / garbage.

**Similar Questions**

- [Storing sensitive data in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229119/storing-sensitive-data-in-memory)

PHP specific and advises writing something not in PHP to store the credentials...which is exactly the problem I am trying to solve.

- [Store password temporarily in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031739/store-password-temporarily-in-memory)

Android application lifecycle specific.  I already know the storage duration for my secrets will be the lifetime of the application.

Comment: Question:  If someone has an app installed that can scan the memory of your app; what else can they do?  If the computer is already compromised do you need to worry about memory scanning.  You need to develop your thread model 1st before worrying above application-implementation details.

Comment: This is more suited for https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can this be migrated to security.stackexchange.com if it is better suited there?  I honestly wasn't sure since this deals with nuts-and-bolts programming.

Comment: @RichardCritten My goal is to keep the API secrets secure.  As long as these are safe a malicious actor can cost me time and inconvenience but not 'direct' assets.  No doubt these are very important concerns in their own right but beyond the scope of my immediate inquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have an area of static memory (largish buffer in your application which holds a per application launch encryption key.

1. Encrypt all your live secrets with the encryption key
2. Any memory which uses unencrypted secrets is cleared with a secure memset.
3. Keep memory used for encryption separate from normal memory (special new/delete to a mmap area).

This would result in....

1. Plain view of your secrets would not be possible.  This prevents leaking of your information by heartbleed type of bugs.  Although un- reset areas of the heap may be published, they are no use as they are encrypted.
2. Plain view secrets have a short life.
3. Encrypted memory would not be adjacent to un-encypted data.

The scheme keeps three areas of memory, the encryption secret which is static, and part of the image memory.

The general application side data - using normal new / delete.

Encrypted data, using a custom new/delete, which is a mmap, and won't share addresses with normal new/delete

Comment: Clever idea; I like the minimization of plaintext and segregation of memory.  If I am understanding correctly, they live keys are stored in memory encrypted with a one-time (probably random) key generated at init.  When I want to use them, the process would be decrypt memory -> use secret -> possibly re-encrypt memory -> nuke temporary memory?  In that case, what is to stop someone from finding the app key and grabbing the secrets using that?

Comment: The scheme was the best I could think of without hardware assistance - if you have only one box, and no hardware assistance, I couldn't think of better.  If you had a TPM, it could be used instead of the application key to encrypt/decrypt your secrets, that would mean at least physical access to get the data.  If you had 2 machines, you could separate the app-key from the live data, but that would cost more latency.

Comment: I suppose *any* memory can be read under the right circumstances and the only true protection will come from hardware.  The perk about this approach is that it can be (fairly) easily upgraded to use a TPM (or similar) in the future.  Accepted and upvoted,

Answer (score -1):

LibSodium is the library you need: https://download.libsodium.org/doc/helpers/memory_management.html

Don't know if this will be available on every possible platform, but in most cases this should help you with your objectives.